# Trying to display custom field data in custom taxonomy all categories list wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have created custom taxonomy stores and added custom field `store_url`. How can I display the store_url from meta data in to the table for each store.

I am not able to find the exact answer. Can anyone please help me? I have also created custom column as Url I need to display data into it